# Storing attributes in static geometry

Tags: opengl, java, voxels

I have a Minecraft like world where I statically create one instance of each tile type, and then place it around the world. However, I don't know how to actually change individual attributes for each tile. For instance, I need to change the lighting per tile, but if I do, it'll change the color of ever single tile. I was thinking about storing two arrays per chunk, one for the tiles and one for the light, and when I want to change the lighting, I can just change the value in the lighting array that coincides with the position in the tile array. However, this will mean I'll have to have store twice as much data per chunk, but is it something I have to accept?

Comment: Sorry 'bout the silly question, but what do you mean by tiles array? Is it a vertex buffer object? If so, does it store the actual vertices of each voxel of a chunk or you're generating the voxels geometry using geometry shader?

Comment: Are you only talking about the light level attribute here? Or do you need an approach that scales to other per-cube attributes as well?

Answer (score -1):

You should check deferred shading system. It implies that you capture the original color of the tiles into a rendertarget and normals and depth of the tiles into other rendertargets (usually done in a single pass with multiple render target technique). You then apply lighting only to those pixels that you store in the rendertargets. So basically your tile data will be completely separated from your lighting and from how you store your tile date in memmory.

Here are some links for deferred shading:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deferred_shading
http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial35/tutorial35.html

You should also study general lighting theory for 3d graphics as it seems to me that you might not completely understand how it works:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_shading
http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/tutorials/ClockworkCoders/lighting.php

Comment: Oh sorry, I don't think you understand what I meant. I'm not performing pixel based lighting on my cubes, I'm performing voxel based lighting. That means every voxel has it's own light level, and I color the tile accordingly. I don't need shaders for this besides the standard fragment shader. Also, please don't tell me I don't know what I'm doing, that's just rude. I know what I'm doing, I've been working with 3D for a year now.